# WPF Stability in VS2008 Express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml, stability

I'm having trouble with stability in the xaml editor.  Restart VS 25 times a day has become tedious.  Are there strategies that would minimize the problem or an open source alternative that provides a visual display?  Any help would be sincerely appreciated!  I don't want to jump out the window but I will...  I WILL!

Comment: Could you explain in what scenario you get crash in Visual Studio.  What specific action makes it crash?

Comment: It's capricious.  I've found that the more hierarchical the page or window is, the more likely it is that it will dump.  I work with small units (contenttemplates, etc) and that minimizes the problem.  Cutting and pasting is a definite no-no.  It really is happening, apparently, at random.

Comment: It just crashed because I had the audacity to minimize an outlined section.

Comment: During cutting and pasting, it would appear that if you allow a duplicate identifier to exist too long it attempts to parse and causes the lock-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the designer, you can just switch to the default editor for XAML files to "Source Code Editor", which still provides completion and is way faster and more responsive.

Comment: Unfortunately, that option isn't available in Express editions AFAIK.  Thanks

Comment: I was incorrect.  The express edition has a 'Show All Settings' check that displays full settings.  If you go to Options >> Text Editor >> File Extension and then add a 'xaml' extension and map it to 'Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding, it seems to do what you suggested.

Thanks again.  Vast improvement!

Comment: 5 days without a crash.  Will you marry me?

Answer (score 1):

The stability of Visual Studio XAML designer greatly improved when I installed the product hotfixes.
Here is one such one that may be of help with your situation:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958017

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have to contact them or can it be downloaded somewhere?  Thanks

Comment: I think that the Express editions are included on the Windows Update site - I've not checked in a while as I've graduated to the full VS2008 at home as well as work.